# How to do this database modification? (foreign key or not)

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a database where we recorded the test results of some product during production (recording date time, serial number of the product, and test result).

When the products are packed we have more than one product per box, and we now we want to record what product goes in what box.

A Box table will be added with ID and whatever other columns we need. A BoxID column will be added to the Product table. Then we have 2 choices:

1) Make BoxID a foreign key linked to the ID columns in the table Box. It's a bit ugly because we'll have to create a special box (with ID 0 or whatever) that will contain all the existing products as we don't have the information for them but some BoxID is required as it's a foreign key.

2) Make BoxID nullable and don't make it a foreign key. The existing products will have NULL for the BoxID which is right as we don't have the information, but it's a bit ugly as it's not enforcing referential integrity for the new products.

Which solution should we choose? Or should we do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a third (junction) table called Product_Box which has a BoxId (FK to Box) and a ProductId (FK to Product).

This means your Box and Product tables can hold information about Products that aren't yet in Boxes, and also Boxes which don't yet have any Products.

When a Product is assigned to a Box, you just put an entry in the new table.

Comment: in addition a unique key on ProductId should enforce that a product can not be put into two boxes.

Answer (score 0):

use a table for products and add a column(BoxID)`Nullable` and products that   contain a BoxID or can not have a boxID